# Identity UserManager UpdateAsync doesn't save custom fields to database

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I've got a .NET Core 2 MVC project set up with AspNet Identity, using an ApplicationUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

In this action I get the FirstName and LastName from a form and want to save it to the database:

```
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

...

var user = _userManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result;
user.FirstName = model.FirstName;
user.LastName = model.LastName;

var result = _userManager.UpdateAsync(user).Result;
```

Everything works (updating password, resetting password, etc.) except using `_userManager.UpdateAsync(user)` to save the custom fields. The returned result.Succeeded is always true, but the changes aren't saved to the database.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit:**
the debug console outputs the following update-query for `UpdateAsync`, which lacks the custom fields:

`UPDATE [AspNetUsers] SET [AccessFailedCount] = @p0, [ConcurrencyStamp] = @p1, [Email] = @p2, [EmailConfirmed] = @p3, [FirstName] = @p4, [LastName] = @p5, [LockoutEnabled] = @p6, [LockoutEnd] = @p7, [NormalizedEmail] = @p8, [NormalizedUserName] = @p9, [PasswordHash] = @p10, [PhoneNumber] = @p11, [PhoneNumberConfirmed] = @p12, [SecurityStamp] = @p13, [TwoFactorEnabled] = @p14, [UserName] = @p15`

Comment: did you generate a migration after adding the custom properties

Comment: Yes, i did. Double checked and the columns exist in the DB

Comment: You could try putting await on the GetUserAsync

Comment: await did seem to fix this. do you know why this fixes it? I thought removing the await just executed the function in the exact same way but non-async...

Comment: It was still running the asnyc function when you set the FirstName and LastName from the model. Removing the await makes it run async, adding await makes it run synchronously.

Comment: Don't use `.Result` unless you are certain the `Task` has completed. It's always better to use `.GetAwater().GetResult()` if you can't use `await` for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, I'll post my comment as an answer.
The GetUserAsync function is still running when you set the FirstName and LastName. Adding await to the GetUserAsync method forces the code to wait for the Async function to complete before continuing.

Comment: OP is calling `.Result` which will await the result (but will be a blocking call and may even result in deadlocks, not a good practice but unlikely the issue here)

Comment: @Tseng is right. This answer is not correct because `.Result` is like a blocking `await` call.